# How to refactor same block of delegate code into a single private method?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have these lines in multiple test methods. Now, trying to create a private method to clean up but not sure how to do it. Any suggestion or pointer would be really helpful. Thanks.

```
    var actualValiationString = string.Empty;
    void messageBuilder(string validationString)
        => actualValiationString = validationString;
    var validationDelegate = new Action<string>(messageBuilder);
```

---

Here's the real test methods look like:

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TryGetBoolTestData))]
public void TryGetBoolShouldReturnBool(
    Dictionary<string,string> metadata,
    bool expectedValue,
    string expectedValidationString
)
{
    var actualValiationString = string.Empty;
    void messageBuilder(string validationString)
        => actualValiationString = validationString;
    var validationDelegate = new Action<string>(messageBuilder);


    DictionaryExtensions.TryGetBool(
        metadata,
        MetadataKey,
        out var response,
        validationDelegate
    );


    response.Should().Be(expectedValue);
    actualValiationString.Should().Be(expectedValidationString);
}

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(GetBoolTestDataWithDefaultValueAndAction))]
public void GetBoolWithDefaultValueAndActionShouldReturnBool(
    Dictionary<string, string> metadata,
    bool defaultValue,
    bool expectedValue,
    string expectedValidateString
)
{
    var actualValiationString = string.Empty;
    void messageBuilder(string validationString)
        => actualValiationString = validationString;
    var validationDelegate = new Action<string>(messageBuilder);


    var actualValue = DictionaryExtensions.GetBool
    (
        metadata,
        MetadataKey,
        defaultValue,
        validationDelegate
    );


    actualValue.Should().Be(expectedValue);
    actualValiationString.Should().Be(expectedValidateString);
}
```

Comment: Show us your attempts at solving this.

Comment: I don't think explicitly creating a delegate is needed; just pass the local function directly. Or write it as a lambda inline. Then the code overhead is lower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bundle the delegate and the local variable in a class:

```
class Validator
{
    public string ActualValidationString { get; private set; } = string.Empty;
    public void Validation(string msg)
    {
        ActualValidationString = msg;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it this way:

```
var validator = new Validator();

var actualValue = DictionaryExtensions.GetBool
(
    metadata,
    MetadataKey,
    defaultValue,
    validator.Validation
);


actualValue.Should().Be(expectedValue);
validator.ActualValidationString.Should().Be(expectedValidateString);
```

Using a class is probably the most idiomatic solution in C#. But if you really insist in a *"single private method"*, one can also implement this in terms of two closures sharing a common variable:

```
 static (Action<string>, Func<string>) CreateValidator()
 {
     string actualString=string.Empty;
     return (s => actualString=s , () => { return actualString;});
 }
```

This has to be used this way:

```
var validator = CreateValidator();

var actualValue = DictionaryExtensions.GetBool
(
    metadata,
    MetadataKey,
    defaultValue,
    validator.Item1
);

actualValue.Should().Be(expectedValue);
validator.Item2().Should().Be(expectedValidateString);
```

This solution is a little shorter than the first one, but may - argueably - a little bit harder to grasp if one isn't used to functional programming.